# Search based on some scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

There is a table in SQL Server ;say TableA with 2 columns(Name and Description) and data in it is like:

```
Name          Description
Person1       Description1
Person2       Description2
Person12      Description12
```

and I have a searchstring="Person+1"
So,what it will do is It searches all the values in table where name or description field contains "Person" and "1" i.e search values are separated by spaces

I am trying to split the searchstring based on '+' and then trying to compare all the values from the table which satisy my desired condition

```
Declare @searchstring varchar(50)
set @searchstring='Person+1'

Select *
from TableA
where Name In Split(searchstring,'+') or
      Description In Split(searchstring,'+')
```

Expected result:

```
Name          Description
Person1       Description1
Person12      Description12
```

Comment: what database are you using ?

Comment: sql is the database

Comment: No, sql is a language. Postgres, MySQL, OracleSQL, SQL Server are databases.

Comment: SQL Server..thanks for correction by the way

Comment: Hmm, when the search string is `'Person+1'` does that match also a value of `'1...Person...' ` or only `'...Person...1'`? And how many searched words can there be, is two a maximum?

Comment: Create 2 variables from the 'Person+1', but using a combination of substring and instring operation, say var1='Person' and var2='1'. Select * from TableA where name like '%var1%' or desc like '%var1%' or name like '%var2%' or desc like '%var2%'

Comment: Search values are separated by space or + symbol ? In your sample search value there is a plus (+) symbol, not a space.

Comment: They are separated by (+)

Comment: @BlackSwan It is not necessary if it will only have 2 vaiables or not.I need to store the values which the user gives

Comment: @stickybit yeah it will match '1.......Person.....' and  '....Person....1' .It only wants to check if the given letters are there are there or not

Comment: And how does the `split()` function look like? Does it return a table? [Edit] your question and show the code of it please.

Comment: @stickybit ..I am trying to use a pre-defined function ..I saw in links this function works..but i am getting error while using this

Comment: There is a [`string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function built in since version 2016. But there's no function named `split()`.

Comment: @stickybit I have embedded a image along with question,please look at it  ..I had tried 'string_split' but it shows it is not an in built function and then I tried ' Split' and this also shows it shows it is not an in built function

Comment: I told you, it's built in since version 2016... Have you checked your server version? It's likely lower.

Comment: @stickybit yeah it's 2014 version...any alternative to string_split for this older version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First you have to create this function** (Which I found on internet)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitLike](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1), @StrVal varchar(50), @EndVal varchar(50))
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@StrVal + @slice + @EndVal)

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

**Now here comes the query**

```
--Search Query
DECLARE @query AS VARCHAR(100) = 'Person+2'

--Create Temp Table
DECLARE @Prefixes TABLE (Prefix VARCHAR(100))

--Calling SplitLike function to get each item with '%' to apply like operator
INSERT INTO @Prefixes (Prefix)
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SplitLike](@query, '+', '%', '%')

SELECT DISTINCT Search.* FROM Search 
LEFT JOIN @Prefixes pfn ON Search.Name LIKE pfn.Prefix 
LEFT JOIN @Prefixes pfd ON Search.[Description] LIKE pfd.Prefix
```

Comment: Thanks for the function @Aamir.But,I am unable to see the table name (for my case  'TableA') which I need to  mention in the query

Comment: Replace Search with your tablename

Comment: The split function works fine for me but the query isn't working as expected for me..could you please elaborate if ossible why you are using left join

Comment: What are you expecting from the query? Well left join will work like OR operator for searching in Name or Description field and if you convert that left join into inner then it will work as AND operator and only return those records in which your query found in Name and Description both columns

Comment: Thanks Aamir,by the way I found a way.I will post

Answer (score 0):

I think the syntax you want is:

```
Select *
from TableA
where Name In (select value from Split(@searchstring, '+')) or
      Description In (select value from Split(searchstring, '+'));
```

Prior to SQL Server 2016, you need to find your own `split()` function.  There are many examples on the web.

Comment: Split doesn't work for me in 2014 version of SQL Server management Studio

Comment: Split is a user defined table valued function but this is not your scenario because it will return exact match and you are looking to compare with like operator

Comment: @AamirNakhwa yeah you are correct.So, do I have to create a function for Split or can I use an predefined  function..any idea?

Comment: Well, there is no pre-defined function for your scenario. You have to create one for it. I have done something familiar before, let me check if I can find it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple `Replace` function to replace the separated character in search sring.

```
Declare @searchstring varchar(50)
set @searchstring='Person+1'

Select *
from TableA
where (Name LIKE REPLACE(@searchstring,'+','')+'%' or
      Description LIKE REPLACE(@searchstring,'+','')+'%')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But what this will do is replace '+' with empty string and then say searchString 'Person+2' becomes Person2 and  I will get result as  :                                      Person2       Description2                                                                                          but I need result as  :                                                                                                Person2       Description2   and
Person12      Description12

Comment: yes, that's what i have thought but `IN` will match the whole string that's why i have used `LIKE` operator. it'll give the expected output.

Comment: please check my edited comment..may be with some modification ,your solution would work for me.I liked you idea ,though

Comment: just try this solution, it'll give you the expected result.
`LIKE` operator instead of `IN` will do that for you.

Comment: It won't..say I want to search for 'Person+2'. It will be changed to 'Person2'.With this solution it will check for 'Person','2','n2 etc.And if it finds a match n2 it will return that result which is not what I need .I need values which have substring 'Person' and substring '2'

Answer (score 0):

The split function is same as @Aamir's. Please see above.

The query part:

```
SELECT t1.[name]
FROM #Table1 t1
CROSS APPLY #Table2 t2
GROUP BY t1.[name]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN (t1.[name] LIKE '%' + t2.[name] + '%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #Table2)
```